# How to convert an array of items to their coressponding array of id

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I have a table in my MySQL database which contains ingredients as follows:

```
id ingredient

1   egg
2   peanut
3  treenut
4   oil
```

now i have an array as ingredients=[peanut,oil,egg]

I have to convert this array to corresponding array of id as follows:

ingredients=[2,4,1]
can anyone help??

thanks in advance...

Comment: add some code you have tried.

Comment: `array_flip()` will switch the array keys with the items. http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php

Comment: Where do the ingredients come from? I assume they originate from the database anyway so where you are getting the names you should be able to change it to return the IDS

Comment: the query should look like `"SELECT id FROM table WHERE igredient in (".implode($ingredients,",").");"`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ingridents = array("peanut", "oil", "eg");
$newArray = array();
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id, ingrident FROM ingridents WHERE ingrident IN (".implode(",", $ingridents).")");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) {
    $newArray[$row['ingrident']] = $row['id'];
}

echo $newArray['peanut']; // would echo out the ID of peanut
```

Answer (score 1):

try this ...

```
$ingredients = array("peanut", "oil", "egg");

$ingredients = "'".implode("','", $ingredients)."'";
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id, ingredient FROM table WHERE ingredient IN ($ingredients)");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query) {
    $ingredient_ids[] = $row['id'];
}
```